# IIB ESQL XML Validations

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Input XML:

```
<Green>
    <Fruits>Apple</Fruits>
    <Vegetables>
        <1>Beans</1>
        <2>Carrot</2>
    </Vegetables>
    <LivingThings @Type = Bird>Parrot</LivingThings>
    <NonLivingThings>Car</NonLivingThings>
</Green>
```

I want to check whether all Field elements under the Root 'Green' is exist and not empty.

I need to throw two different exceptions for each error:

For non existent field - Field not exist;
For empty values         - Not a valid value

```
IF(FIELDTYPE(ref.fruits)IS NULL OR FIELDTYPE(ref.Vegetables)IS NULL OR FIELDTYPE(ref.livingthins)IS NULL OR 
                                    FIELDTYPE(ref.nonlivingthing)IS NULL) THEN
                                    Throw USER EXCEPTION MESSAGE 2000 VALUES ('Field Not Present'); 
                                ELSEIF(FIELDVALUE(ref.fruits)= '' OR FIELDVALUE(ref.Vegetables)= '' OR FIELDVALUE(ref.livingthins)= '' OR 
                                    FIELDVALUE(ref.nonlivingthing)= '') THEN
                                    Throw USER EXCEPTION MESSAGE 2004 VALUES ('Invalid Value'); 
                                ELSE                                    
                                    Propagate to terminal 'out1';                                   
                                END IF;
```

Here is the solution, but i need to concatenate the exact field which is null or empty to my exception messages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

If your using a SOAP Service you can define the requirements in your XSD. So, in your SOAP Input you can enable the message validation.

Comment: Hi Rafael, thanks for your inputs. But the service which i am designing doesnt involved SOAP.

Comment: Which Input are you using. If you can model this using a XSD or DFDL it´s possible to enable validation for any input node.

Comment: I am designing a MQ service.

Comment: What is the format of your message, XML or JSON? JSON does not enforce a schema so you can you validate by coding. If your message is a XML format you can model using a XSD and enable validation in the MQ Input Node.

Comment: XML. I have updated my solution above. I need to add the empty or non existent fields directly to my exception message. do you have any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to check if a field is null in the input tree you can use: EXISTS(ref.fruits[]). Checkin if null may not work as it seems.
Secondly, you can use the "ResetContentDescriptor" node inside the flow to validate or revalidate the XML message. Please check the node documentation on the knowledge centre [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac04810_.htm). I hope this helps.